# $$passToExceptionHandler in AngularJS not throwing exception

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS version of 1.7.2 and got an exception with this message

> Cannot read property 'dataItem' of undefined

and it is not throwing into console / customExceptionHandling Service Because code in AngularJS is below:

```
catch (e) {
    rejectPromise(promise, e);
    // This error is explicitly marked for being passed to the $exceptionHandler 
    if (e && e.$$passToExceptionHandler === true) {     
        exceptionHandler(e); 
    }
}
```

that $$passToExceptionHandler is not present in e object and exceptionHandler function is not calling.

Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: The same issue is encountered on angular 1.7.8

Answer (score 3):

You might have disabled reporting unhandled rejected promises with this line:

`qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);`

But generally more information about the error source are required to give you better answer.

Comment: You are my savior

Comment: Fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work, set $$passToExceptionHandler to all "Error" instance like:

```
Error.prototype.$$passToExceptionHandler = true
```

Comment: Confirmed: Adding the suggested line causes the exception to appear in the Chrome dev console.

Comment: I like this solution - it seems like a good way to force AngularJS to log all errors to the console, even those that occur within promise chains. I'm a bit nonplussed as to why this isn't the default behaviour...